# Boot issue after plugging m2 ssd

Tags: boot

I have an ASUS TUF GAMING B550 plus, when i boot after plugging my brand new m2 ssd it goes into BIOS and I can only see the m2 disk and I can't boot to windows . I can't see my other disks 1 SSD with my OS(windows) on it and one for extra storage HDD

Comment: Sounds like UEFI boot settings were modified - ensure CSM [Legacy] Mode is disabled and Secure Boot is enabled

Comment: Which model is the M.2 ?

Comment: model : msi spatium m461 500gb

Comment: @JW0914 here's what it looks like in BIOS when M2 is plugged URL : https://imageupload.io/VGpEyCXDq4zDZK9 when m2 is uplugged URL :https://imageupload.io/JobduZVXbf6VrDg

Comment: A long shot: Try to change in the BIOS the disk interface from AHCI to RAID. Return it to AHCI if there is any problem.

Comment: I tried switching to UEFI mode enabled Secure boot even turned AHCI to RAID tried them together at once different combination doesn't seem to work all I managed to do is make M2 appear and I can boot on it but other disks won't

Comment: @Ibrahimzerzeri BIOS and UEF aren't the same things - you have UEFI. Please don't enable/disable random things, as it's not going to resolve and will create more issues. Unless you configured your drives in a RAID setup, it needs to remain AHCI. CSM [Legacy] Mode should never be enabled, as it's sole purpose was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017 (Win 7+ supports EFI boot). The only thing I can think of if the motherboard is no longer detecting other drives besides the NVMe is it doesn't have enough PCIe lanes to use SATA and NVMe at rhe same time - check mb manual

Answer (score 0):

Solved it finally moved m2 from bottom slot to top slot and it seemed to work with default BIOS settings